# @media only screen query not working

Tags: css

I am working on the [this](http://labelleforme.co.uk/?GD_NONCE=72a809cb93) website. I have added the following code to make it hide the bottom menu when someone opens it on a mobile device,

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
.footer-p-1{
    display:none;
}
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
.footer-p-1{
    display:none;
}
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {
.footer-p-1{
    display:none;
}

}

/* ----------- Kindle Fire HD 8.9" ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
.footer-p-1{
    display:none;
}

}
```

For some reason, the css does not work. Please guide me where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I cannot see the CSS rules in any file of yours. You havent' added that yet?

Comment: @ManojKumar: http://labelleforme.co.uk/wp-content/themes/labelle/style.css?ver=4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The browser currently outputs your CSS as:

[image]

`-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` is not valid any more as the w3.org CSS validator outputs:

[image]

**Solution:**

`-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` is deprecated and needs to be converted to `min-resolution`

You will need to unprefix the media query condition:

[**Unprefix Webkit device pixel ratio**](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must not define Min-max but if you want to hide it for mobile device like with widt < 800px try this:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .footer-p-1{
       display:none;
   }
}
```

comment the other and try only with this